# How to use fetched api result in other methods or functions in Nuxt3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

How to work with fetched data from an API in Nuxt3?

For example, I want to set metatags from the API's results, but it throws an error of undefined. I am unable to access `pageData` in `useHead`.

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue"
const { apiUrl } = useRuntimeConfig()
const route = useRoute()

const { data: pageData } = await useFetch(
  `${apiUrl}/misc/cmspage/61785b119b4eb50d8d625621`
)

useHead({
   title: this.pageData.seo.metatitle
})
</script>
```

This is the result of the API.

```js
{
  seo: {
    metatitle: "SomeTitle",
    metadesc: "SomeDescriptions",
    metakeywords: "SomeKeywords",
  },
  pagename: "XXXXX",
  faqs: [],
  topDestinations: [],
  pageId: "61785b119b4eb50d8d625621",
  id: "61785b119b4eb50d8d625621",
}
```

Comment: Did you tried without the `this` like `pageData.seo.metatitle`?

Comment: yes i tried this as well, it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you see the values if you `console.log`?

Comment: its undefined when i console.log(pageData.seo.metatitle). but if i do console.log(pageData) then it prints values and if i do console.log(pageData.seo) then its undefined as well.

Comment: What about `pageData.value.seo.metatitle`?

Comment: then it prints value.

Comment: Prints `'value'` or `'SomeTitle'`? Because this is a "Vue3 thing" and this is how it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `pageData.value.seo.metatitle` to print the content of your ref.

More details are available here: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#reactive-variables-with-ref (switch to `composition` on the top right sidebar `API preference`)